# How does chrome detects reload vs navigation in window.onbeforeunload in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

My question is mainly related to differentiate `reload` event vs `navigation` event in browser. But after Googling and SO(ing) it's not possible. But some how chrome knows how to change heading of dialog box if it's `reload` or `navigation` attempt.

#### Navigation attempt(using keyboard shortcut and browser's buttons):

[image: Navigation attempt in dialog box]

#### Reload attempt(using keyboard shortcut and browser's button):

[image: Reload in dialog box]

How does Chrome do that?

Thanks

Edit : Reload and navigation attempt explained.

Comment: How did you try to reload?

Comment: @GHOST93 Using keyboard and browser key both.

Comment: Here is what I did, click on URL bar and hit Enter button and check the alert message, it will display navigation

Comment: So basically it identifies the keyperss event for F5 or Reload button to display the header this is what I think can be.

Comment: One more note, if you hit close button of browser alert header will be of navigation.

Comment: @GHOST93 Thanks. I am looking for code for the same.

Comment: What I will do is bind the F5 with my button of reload so that I need to take care for the keypress event of F5 only. Hope this will help :)

Comment: @GHOST93 It's not universal, there is 'Ctrl + R'/'Command + R'/'Command + Shift + R', on mobile mobile it's infinity scroll functionality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95682/discussion-between-ghost93-and-igaurav).